# Python Matplotlib: How to set x-axis tick resolution?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been googling for the answer for a while but can't figure out a straightforward solution, so I am posting my question here at the risk of asking a duplicate question.

Suppose I am plotting a time-series graph like the one below.

- How can I set the distance of major/minor ticks to be every 1/3/6/12... month?
- How can I set the resolution of major/minor ticks such that the total number of ticks is x?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
t = np.arange(np.datetime64('2005-02-25'), np.datetime64('2019-02-25'), np.timedelta64(1,'D'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(t), 3),columns=['A','B','C']).cumsum()
df['Date'] = t
df=df.set_index('Date')

ax=df.plot(figsize=(16,8))
ax.grid(which='both')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second question (certain total number of xticks) is quite simple to solve:

```
start = t[0].astype(int)
stop = t[-1].astype(int)
N = 7
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.linspace(start, stop, N).astype(int))
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(np.linspace(start, stop, N).astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

The first one could be solved the same way, although this is not really easy to read, because of the different datatypes which are desired at different places...

However, the main idea is to use list comprehension to create a list of first-january-Dates for the major ticks, and a list of e.g. first-of-every-third-month-dates for the minor ticks:

```
xl = ax.get_xlim()
import datetime as DT
start = t[0].astype(DT.date)
stop = t[-1].astype(DT.date)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([np.datetime64(DT.date(y, 1, 1)).astype(int) for y in range(start.year, stop.year+1)])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.array([[np.datetime64(DT.date(y, m, 1)).astype(int) for m in range(1,13,3)] for y in range(start.year-1, stop.year+1)]).flatten(), minor = True)
ax.xaxis.grid(which='minor', ls=':')
ax.set_xlim(xl)
```

[image]